"Testing my twttr" error with check50 - CS50P PSET 5
Goal is to test twttr.py with test_twttr.py
twttr.py:
def main():

    user = str(input("Input: "))

    print(shorten(user))


def shorten(word):
    word = str(word)
    result = ''

    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() not in vowels:
            result += letter

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

test_twttr.py:
from twttr import shorten

def test_default():
    assert shorten("") == ""

def test_uCase():
    assert shorten("twITter") == "twTtr"

def test_lCase():
    assert shorten("TWitTER") == "TWtTR"

def test_int():
    assert shorten(0) == "0"
    assert shorten(452) == "452"
    assert shorten("21") == "21"

def test_float():
    assert shorten(3.14) == "3.14"
    assert shorten("2.71e") == "2.71"

def test_punc():
    assert shorten("..,-!?ab:i") == "..,-!?b:"

Getting this error with check50 even though all tests passed in pytest:

:) test_twttr.py exist
:( correct twttr.py passes all test_twttr checks
    expected exit code 0, not 1
:| test_twttr catches twttr.py without vowel replacement
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| test_twttr catches twttr.py without capitalized vowel replacement
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| test_twttr catches twttr.py without lowercase vowel replacement
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| test_twttr catches twttr.py omitting numbers
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| test_twttr catches twttr.py printing in uppercase
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| test_twttr catches twttr.py omitting punctuation
    can't check until a frown turns upside down

When self checking code with pytest all tests pass but when check50 uses pytest it returns exit code 1. My guess is that this is due to check50 having its own "correct" version of twttr.py on which it uses my test_twttr.py.

I don't think we can help without seeing the exact error from check50, which it unfortunately does not show.

How, exactly, do you run the check50 program?  Is that done on your local computer, or is it a submission on a website, or what?

check50 is used by Harvard's CS50 program through edx. It is a submission on a website.

I can only guess that your real test_twttr.py module does not match the one you posted here.

When I tested out your two files, it worked fine when both files were in the same directory/folder and I got an exit code of "0".  When I temporarily renamed file "twttr.py" to another value and retried program "test_twttr.py" I got an error message of "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twttr'" and the exit code was "1".  So that leads me to the suggestion of double-checking that the file "twttr.py" is in the same directory/folder as file "test_twttr.py".
